# How to make curl use specified ip instead of setting it in /etc/hosts?

Tags: linux, curl

Hi I am trying to use `curl` to send a request to a specified ip address, since if I set it in `/etc/hosts`, it wouldn't immediately work. So is there a way to do that in curl command? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes.
A example is shown in the brand new book of Daniel, the author of curl.

https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/connections/name => Provide a custom IP for a name

And you can also look into the manpage

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

```
--resolve <host:port:address>

Provide a custom address for a specific host and port pair. Using this, you can make the curl requests(s) use a specified address and prevent the otherwise normally resolved address to be used. Consider it a sort of /etc/hosts alternative provided on the command line. The port number should be the number used for the specific protocol the host will be used for. It means you need several entries if you want to provide address for the same host but different ports.

The provided address set by this option will be used even if -4, --ipv4 or -6, --ipv6 is set to make curl use another IP version.

This option can be used many times to add many host names to resolve.

(Added in 7.21.3)
```